# Input pattern, at least 1 non-whitespace character

Tags: html, regex

I'm wanting to rewrite the following as a HTML pattern:

```
if (/\S/.test(myString)) {
    // string is not empty and not just whitespace
}
```

So

```
<input pattern="\S" required">

if ($('form :invalid'))
    console.log('empty');
else
    console.log('has non-whitespace char');
```

The problem is my pattern doesn't work the same as the test string. I'm wanting to check if there is at least 1 non-whitespace character.

Comment: So, correct string is the one that has at least 1 non-whitespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute requires full string match and the pattern is automatically anchored (no need to use `^` and `$`). Thus, to require at least 1 non-whitespace, use

```
pattern="[\s\S]*\S[\s\S]*"
```

Since you are validating a multiline text (i.e. text containing newline symbols), you need to match them with `[\s\S]` or with `[^]` constructs.

**The *pattern* attribute will work with *`<input>`* element only**.

**To validate a *textarea* field**, you can create a custom `pattern` attribute validation:

```js
$('#test').keyup(validateTextarea);

function validateTextarea() {
        var errorMsg = "Please match the format requested.";
        var textarea = this;
        var pattern = new RegExp('^' + $(textarea).attr('pattern') + '$');
        var hasError = !$(this).val().match(pattern); // check if the line matches the pattern
         if (typeof textarea.setCustomValidity === 'function') {
            textarea.setCustomValidity(hasError ? errorMsg : '');
         } else { // Not supported by the browser, fallback to manual error display
            $(textarea).toggleClass('error', !!hasError);
            $(textarea).toggleClass('ok', !hasError);
            if (hasError) {
                $(textarea).attr('title', errorMsg);
             } else {
                $(textarea).removeAttr('title');
             }
         }
         return !hasError;
    }
```

```css
:valid, .ok {
    background:white;
    color: green;
}
:invalid, .error {
    background:yellow;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="test" pattern="[\S\s]*\S[\S\s]*" id="test"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ckz29Lr/1/ this doesn't appear to be working correctly. If the textarea is just whitespace that it should fail.

Comment: It should fail if you enter a whitespace and no other non-whitespace character. Atm the textarea goes valid with just a whitespace :(

Comment: HTML5 textarea element does not support the pattern attribute. So, this should be done with the JQuery means. You only asked about `<input>` element, so I posted what is valid for `<input>`...